# How to parse this example code of XML with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

So I am fairly new to XML and HTML and I've been looking up guides on w3schools.com. Below are two files associated with one such example and it's about parsing code. I think I understand somewhat how the code works and it works swell with their online "try it yourself". My problem is that I can't get it to work after I download the files. Perhaps I don't have the directories set up right or maybe I'm missing something altogether.

XML code:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

(this is saved as cd_catalog.xml)

HTML Table Code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

(This is saved as display_table.html)

If I'm missing something please tell me I've been trying to research it myself for days.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? Are you serving the files from a web server, or just in a folder?

Comment: I just have them in a folder. To test it I've just been trying to run the .html file in IE but every time I do that nothing but a blank screen opens up.

Comment: Try running it in Chrome, press F12 for the developer console (your new best friend) and see if it shows a security exception. You can't load files from the filesystem with JavaScript, to prevent websites just reading your data, so it's easiest to install Apache locally if you need to do stuff like this.

Comment: So if I hosted it online how would I need any special software?

Comment: You would still be hosting it locally, just through a webserver. Apache is fairly easy to set up and free - http://httpd.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `onreadystatechange'-Event:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
       xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");

    }
};
```

If you dont wait for this event and this state,`xmlhttp.responseXML` will be empty.

Comment: Better add a comment instead of downvote a correct piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

i just tested your script, try to remove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

from the cd_catalog.xml

Comment: I tried this but I don't believe it works based on what Evan said in the comments. JS won't allow it since they are locally stored files for security reasons.

Comment: This would just make it invalid XML.